# Java - Converting a console game into a applet

Tags: java, applet, console, converters

I have recently made a Java console game with quite a bit of code, is the there a way to convert this into a applet **or** play it on the internet without having to download the application?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You mean, without modifying the source code for the game?

Answer (score 2):

> ..is the there a way to convert this into a applet ..

The task of converting the console based game into a rich client (or web app.) based game depends upon how clearly the game concept and structure has been separated from the UI (the console, in this case).

If the games can be encompassed within a text console and 2 or 3 other controls, look to [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) for the output.

[image]

(Screenshot obtained from the linked article at Rob Camick's 'Java Tips Weblog'.)

BTW - Even if deploying from the internet, it would be better to wrap it in a `JFrame` and deploy it using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

> ..or play it on the internet without having to download the application?

Convert it to JSP/Servlet (make it a web app.).

Note that a console based app., an applet, an app. launched with JWS - would all need to 'download' the app. (to the user's local disks), but the last two would be largely invisible to the user, which is often what developers mean when they say 'no download'.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to adapt a [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) to act like a console UI.  As a Swing component, it would be easy to wrap it in a Java Applet.  These may give you some ideas:

- [jTextArea as IO console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017148/jtextarea-as-io-console)
- [Using JTextArea to simulate a text console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886513/using-jtextarea-to-simulate-a-text-console)
- [show data on a JTextArea instead of console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680318/show-data-on-a-jtextarea-instead-of-console)