# JFrame console/Enter and display text

Tags: java, swing, console, jtextfield, jtextarea

I am new to swing and was wondering if anybody knew how to make a component of a JFrame that can display text in the same style as a console, as well as take user input in the form of a string. I heard some talk of `JTextArea` and `JTextField` but I don't quite understand their use (or how to to use them).

Comment: `display text in the same style as a console` is quite board as console's look different on different platforms.  Start by taking a look at [Creating a GUI in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [How to use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for some starting tips.  User input can be achieved through a `JTextArea` or `JTextField` depending on your needs...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886513/using-jtextarea-to-simulate-a-text-console, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017148/jtextarea-as-io-console, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357418/how-to-display-console-output-in-java-jtextarea-one-by-one-in-a-loop-when-button, etc...

Comment: ehrm... @WilliamGaul, I feel stupid, I couldnt find that. Guess I just wasnt looking hard enough

Answer (score 2):

> JTextField = single line
>
> JTextArea = multi line

that prety much what you need to know here and for a console style you probably will go for the Area

```
JTextField myjtf = new JTextField("whatever you want");


JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(
"This is an editable JTextArea. " +
"A text area is a \"plain\" text component, " +
"which means that although it can display text " +
"in any font, all of the text is in the same font."
);// found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html
```

Answer (score 0):

`JTextArea` is used for writing/displaying multiple line text and `JTextField` is used for writing or displaying single line text.

If you want to set text in JTextArea- `jTextArea.setText("YOUR MULTI LINE TEXT");`
If you want to set text in JTextField- `jTextField.setText("YOUR SINGLE LINE TEXT");`

In this way you can use these 2 components.

You can even retrieve text from these components using `getText()` method.